# Ruby on Rails 4 Parsing first 3 RSS items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently making a website in RoR 4 and I want to include RSS from my blog on the front page. However, currently I get all of the articles from the blog while I need only first 3.

I'm fairly new to rails and I couldn't find any pointers to how I could do such thing.

My current code in the controller is:

```
  def index
    require 'rss'
        @rss = RSS::Parser.parse(open('FEED_URL').read, false)
  end
```

I imagine I could simply cut the `@rss` after the third element after it has been parsed, but that seems to me a bit dirty in Ruby. Is there a better way to do it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS.html), I'd take a gander and try...

```
@rss = RSS::Parser.parse(open('FEED_URL').read, false).items[0..2]
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!
Just for future reference I'd like to add, that accessing elements now doesn't work by: `@rss.items.each` but through `@rss.each`

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

[Feedjira](http://feedjira.com/) is a fantastic RSS parser. Just do:

```
Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse('FEED_URL').entries[0,3]
```